# Display JSON in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

output:

```
{"non_field_errors":["My error msg"]}
```

How can I display first error of `non_field_errors`?

`console.log(xhr.responseText['non_field_errors'])` not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON string in `responseText` to an object, you can then access its properties. Try this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(json.non_field_errors[0]); // = "My error msg"
```

Comment: Dot notation is better than brackets notation to access object properties. ^

Answer (score 1):

The `xhr.responseText` will be a string. So you need to parse it as JSON. Use this way:

```
xhr.responseText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(xhr.responseText['non_field_errors'][0]);
```

Or in better ways:

```
data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(data.non_field_errors[0]);
```